# How to customize link-buttonsize in Jquery EasyUI, instead of using the builtin small or large size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I want to build some mobile webpages with some icons. Some of these are normal sized icons and some are large icons. Like the "Top Sites" icons in browsers (https://www.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/firefox-62-new-search-tab.png).

I don't know much about javascript so I want to write as fewer code as possible. So I found EasyUI maybe suitable... But the problem is the builtin icon style is very tiny. They only have two options size:small size:large 
And even set it to large, the actuall image size is still very tiny only allowing 32p*32px image.

For demo, go to this page and (https://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=LinkButton&theme=material-teal&dir=ltr&pitem=&sort=asc) and click "Linkbutton Size".

Looking at their demo code, the size is set like this.

```
 <div style="padding:5px 0;">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-add'">Add</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-remove'">Remove</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-save'">Save</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-cut',disabled:true">Cut</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton">Text Button</a>
    </div>
    <p>Large Buttons</p>
    <div style="padding:5px 0;">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-large-picture',size:'large',iconAlign:'top'">Picture</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-large-clipart',size:'large',iconAlign:'top'">Clip Art</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-large-shapes',size:'large',iconAlign:'top'">Shapes</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-large-smartart',size:'large',iconAlign:'top'">SmartArt</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-large-chart',size:'large',iconAlign:'top'">Chart</a>
    </div>
```

There are some parser in their *.js files to process the size:large or size:small setted here. But I don't know how to make another size, like size:extralarge so I can make it looks like the "Top Sites".

Or could someone recommend another framework to build the webpages?

Comment: can you use css to override the existing style

Comment: @Deepak I tried this. The 32px is written in its easyui.css file (.l-btn-large .l-btn-icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-top: -16px;
})When I modify the css, change 32px to 100px, the layout becomes very bad... I don't know how to make it looks good...

Answer (score 4):

I guess u can Use simple style to get your customize size. like:

```
<div style="padding:5px 0;">
    <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" style="height:50px; width:50px" data-options="iconCls:'icon-add'">Add</a>
    <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" style="height:50px; width:50px" data-options="iconCls:'icon-remove'">Remove</a>
    <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" style="height:50px; width:50px" data-options="iconCls:'icon-save'">Save</a>
    <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" style="height:50px; width:50px" data-options="iconCls:'icon-cut',disabled:true">Cut</a>
    <a href="#" style="height:50px; width:50px" class="easyui-linkbutton">Text Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have figured out. There are many places in the css, I have to add change every large to extralarge and reset the values in css. Then it looks good.